# Bridge Crossing - Classic Puzzle

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge

Problem - The classic puzzle of finding the minimum amount of time required to cross a bridge given that only two people can cross the bridge at any one time.
Since they have only one flashlight (it's dark and they need the flashlight), the two people move at the speed of the slower one.

Constraints - Upto 6 people (although it should work for a higher number of people)

Input - Number of people (up to 6 tested) & Sorted vector of time required by each person to cross the bridge.

Output - Minimum time possible

```
int main()
{
  vector<int> v; int n; int time;
  int items;
  int k = 2;
  cin>>items;
  for (int i = 0; i < items; i++)
  {
    cin >> n;
    v.push_back(n);
   }

  if (v.size() == 1)
  {
    cout << v[0];
    return 0;
  }
  int last = v.size() - 1;
  time = v[0] + v[1] + v[last] + v[1];

  while (last-k >= 2)
  {
    time += v[0] + v[last - k];
    k++;
  }
  time = time + v[1];

  cout << time;
  return 0;
}
```

Note : Code will not work for 2 people, missed a special case.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast I assumed the code appeared broken and was difficult to understand as mentioned by forsvarir. Won't edit further

Comment: Given the lack of descriptive variable naming, perhaps you should add a reference to more detailed background info in the question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_and_torch_problem

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong. It outputs 253 for the speeds 1 2 3 80 80 80 80, but I can do it in 175.

Comment: @RolandIllig See the constraints. I've written upto 6 only

Comment: @borb183 in that case, leave out the 3, resulting in 1 2 80 80 80 80. That can be solved in less than 240.

Answer (score 4):

The overwhelming first impression I get from your code is that without the text description above, I wouldn't have a clue what it is you're trying to do.  A lot of these types of problems have *some* kind of prompting which helps, however your code doesn't have that, its only output is `time` after it's finished.

The two main improvements I'd suggest are:

- Put your code in a function that defines an interface.
- Use variable names that have some kind of meaning.

Implementing these two basics would go a long way to making your code easier to follow.

For example, your `vector v` might be people?!?

You could have a method `calculate_minimum_time_to_cross_bridge`, which took in a list of people and returned the time.

Whilst your variable names might have meaning to you, they have no meaning a new reader without context.

One final point is that whilst you can do this:

```
vector<int> v; int n; int time;
```

It's generally considered bad form.  One declaration per line means the declarations are less likely to get lost.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Edited the variables to reflect some meaning. Will implement the method soon. Do you think the code is logically correct? I just formed a conjecture. Worked for upto 6 people

Comment: @borb183 Honestly, I'm not sure, I get a different answer to you, I'd have to see a worked example.  By my logic, you basically have two cases.  If there is only 1 person, it takes that amount of time.  If you have (2 to n) people, then it takes the sum of the times for the n-1 slowest people + the time for the fastest person * n-2, which is the number of times they'd have to walk back.  So for 2 people with speeds 2 and 3, the time should be 3 (they walk across together).  With your algorithm,  I am getting 14, however I'm not sure what order your elements are supposed to be in.

Answer (score 4):

## Advice

- The biggest problem with this code is variable naming

  `v` should be `person` or `people`

  `items` should be `count` or `numPeople`

  `n` should be `speed`
- Create functions to separate workflow

  I would create a function that receives user input and another function that computes the minimum crossing time.  Both of those functions would be called from `main`.
- Whenever you the size of a `vector` beforehand you should either use the [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector),  [`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve), or [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to prevent reallocations that would occur from naively adding elements.  Which one you need depends on the context.
- Use 4-space indentation or tabs (no need to start a religious war over which is better).  2-space indentation is awful for readability imo.
- After the initial step of taking the `last` and `(last-1)` person across the bridge, you need to take person `1` to  person `last-2`.  The way you wrote your while loop obfuscates this process.

## Suggested Code

```
struct Person
{
    unsigned int walking_speed;
};

std::vector<Person> get_people(unsigned int n)
{
    // Create the n people now
    std::vector<Person> person(n);
    std::cout << "Enter ascending walking speeds for " << n << " people\n";

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        unsigned int speed;

        std::cout << "Enter person " << i << " walking speed: ";
        std::cin >> speed;

        person[i].walking_speed = speed;
    }

    return person;
}

unsigned int get_minimum_crossing_time(unsigned int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    auto person = get_people(n);

    if (n < 3)
    {
        return person.back().walking_speed;
    }
    else if (n == 3)
    {
        // Unfortunately the method below does not
        // give the minimum time for three people

        // Person 0 and 1 cross from A to B
        // Person 0 crosses back to A
        // Person 0 and 2 cross from A to B
        return person[1].walking_speed + person[0].walking_speed + person[2].walking_speed; 
    }

    unsigned int time_taken = 0;

    // Person 0 and Person 1 cross from A to B
    time_taken += person[1].walking_speed;

    // Person 1 crosses back to A
    time_taken += person[1].walking_speed;

    // Person (n-2) and Person (n-1) cross from A to B
    time_taken += person[n-1].walking_speed;

    // Person 0 goes back and forth to escort everyone else
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < n-2; ++i)
    {
        // Person 0 crosses back to A
        time_taken += person[0].walking_speed;

        // Person 0 and Person i cross from A to B
        time_taken += person[i].walking_speed;
    }

    return time_taken;
}
```

I am aware `person = get_people(n)` is a bit confusing, but I prefer addressing people as `person[i]` in the code rather than `people[i]`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. To point out, I do count the time it takes for v[0] to return.  v[last-k] would be the time for v[0] and v[last-k] to cross the bridge (as it is at the speed of the slower one). Then v[0] returns and thus the total time taken is v[0]  + v[last-k]

Comment: You are right.  That was my fault.  I will remove that part.